# Assign many pandas Dataframe to variables

Tags: python, pandas

I want to assign distinct variable names to a list of 130 dataframes.

With fewer number of dataframes, I can do:

```
df1, df2, df3 = [list of dataframes]
```

However, with 130 of them, there must be a better way to achieve this.

I have tried:

```
[list of dataframe names] = [list of dataframes]
```

But, this does not work.

Ultimately, I want to create a list of dataframes each with distinct variable names, so that I should be able to access each dataframe by variable name.

Comment: @jezrael This is not the same question as "how to split a single dataframe into multiple dataframes". This is asking "how multiple dataframes can each be assigned to different variables". Please refer to me to a duplicate question if there exists one.

Comment: @jezrael Could you please remove "duplicate"? Or please refer me to the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a dictionary is the solution you need and not a list. I'm using a dictionary comprehension below to build it similar to the way you would a list comprehension.

```
dataframes = {k:v for zip(list_of_dataframe_names, list_of_dataframes)}
```

And then whenever you want a certain dataframe just call it from the dictionary

```
needed_dataframe = dataframes[dataframe_name]
```